# My mercurial repository is too large, I need to delete old commits. Is it possible?

Tags: mercurial, filesize

I have a big Mercurial Repository on Google Code Hosting, how can I delete the old commits/revisions? I don't need that old revisions anymore because I have forked it to other repositories.

Comment: Specific question similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683175/reducing-repository-size-in-mercurial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that deleting revisions is anathema to version control :-)

Nevertheless, you might use the `hg convert` options to convert to a new repo with changed revisions. AFAIK using splicemap, you could remove revisions.

But it won't help with the Google repository, because it stays as it is. You will have to delete it (reset as described by Klaim) and push the converted repository.

You can also push the converted repository to another place (other then default repo) because you may have up to 7 repositories on Google Code in one project.

Answer (score 1):

Go in the Administer tab, then click on Reset on the repository you want to delete revisions from, then follow the instructions, depending on what exactly you wanted to do in the end.

Comment: Any mercurial service provider?

Comment: What do you ask exactly? If you're looking for another provider I know about bitbucket.org and sourceforge.net.