# Reducing repository size in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, continuous-integration, tortoisehg, filesize, maven-release-plugin

As my team works on a given project with the source in a Mercurial repository, the repository is obviously growing in size. As such, cloning a repository over the network becomes slower and slower.

Are there any techniques that are used for pruning out older commits or reducing the size of the repo to make the cloning operation faster over a slow network?

(We are using TortoiseHg as the Mercurial client but that (I'm guessing) shouldn't make a difference to the solution to this problem.)

Comment: How often are you cloning the whole repository, btw? I would not expect that cloning is the majority of activity on the repository.

Comment: cloning the whole repository: `mvn release:prepare` does that for every release. Cloudbees Jenkins does that for every build...

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898600/cleaning-out-a-mercurial-repository

Comment: @Guy I'm experiencing the same problem... Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Tarlog: I'm afraid the answers are not out-of-date: Mercurial repositories are still append-only and you cannot leave out old history.

Comment: @Martin Geisler A question: is it possible to 'update' without cloning the whole repository? Usually I 'pull' changes to a local repository and then 'update'. But can I 'update' from remote?

Comment: The closest thing to that would be to download a snapshot like `http://selenic.com/hg/archive/stable.zip`. It's just a zip file with the files from that branch — you can of course not make new commits based on such a file. But for continuous integration it can work fine.

Comment: @Martin Geisler Sounds good. Is there any command I can get it?

Comment: Use any tool that can download a file over HTTP: `wget`, `curl`, etc

Comment: I'm probably missing something... is this zip automatically generated in every Mercurial repository?

Comment: @Martin Geisler Btw, I think your comment regarding the snapshot is worth posting as an answer to the question. With a little explanation how the snapshots are created. Thanks!

Comment: @Tarlog: okay, I've turned it into an answer! Hope you like it, happy new years :-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One option is to [use the `convert` extension to decompose your repository](http://hgtip.com/tips/advanced/2009-11-16-using-convert-to-decompose-your-repository/) to a group of smaller repositories.

> Say you have a repository that has evolved to contain many projects (folders). And you have decided you’d be better off if each project (folder) were a separate repository. You can use the `convert` extension to do just that and retain your changeset history.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a dedicated clone of the remote repo on your computer as a cache for clone operations. So you don't need to transfer the whole repo over the net every time, but only the parts which are not already there.

Answer (score 6):

If you only need the files in a given revision, but never need to examine history or make new commits, then downloading a **snapshot** can be faster.

The normal `hgweb` CGI script [can provide a zip or tar file for any revision](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PublishingRepositories#Allowing_archive_downloads). The archives are generated on the fly. You only need to add

```
[web]
allow_archive = gz, zip, bz2
```

to your configuration file. You can then find archives under URLs like

```
http://server.com/repo/archive/rev.zip
```

Replace the revision number with the branch name it changeset hash you want  Download the file with `wget`, `curl`, or a similar tool.

This strategy only pays off when the history is very large compared to the size of a single changeset.

This can be the case if the repository contains large files that change often. The [largefiles extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/LargefilesExtension) can be an alternative here: it allows you to only download the files needed for the revision you checkout. That way you avoid downloading the history for big files and save significant amounts of bandwidth.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes problems like this can be caused if you have large binary files in your repository. Any updates to them tend to cause large diffs and make the size to go up more drastically than normal.

If this applies to you, it may be worth looking at the [Large-files extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/LargefilesExtension) distributed with Mercurial 2.0. I've not used it personally, and it sounds like it still has some rouge edges, but if includes a command `lfconvert` which will convert the repo for you. You could then try it to see if it clones any quicker.